# PSFTP connection using key authentication

Tags: ssh, sftp, private-key, psftp

Using PuTTY to SSH onto server. But can't work out how to connect to SFTP.

Private key is on a USB, maybe that's where I'm going wrong !?

I have tried various ways e.g. PSFTP, but can't really find a clear answer when key authentication is required.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With `psftp`, use [`-i` switch](https://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/latest/htmldoc/Chapter3.html#using-cmdline-identity) to specify your private key file:

```
psftp -i "C:\path\mykey.ppk" user@example.com
```

---

You can also use Pageant as with PuTTY. Or re-use PuTTY stored session (with private key specified), using `-load` switch.

Comment: That's the one !! Thank you much appreciated :-)